# Is it possible to limit access to field through ACL or drupal permissions?

Tags: drupal, acl

We want to create a user that has read only access to the civicrm database. However, we only want the user to have access to specific info and not for others. For example, the user can only view name, address, and email, and not anything else (like phone or birthday).

I think it can be done for custom fields (through groups) but can this be done for the builtin fields without involving lots of coding/programming?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One option with Drupal for this sort of scenario is to actually keep your 'read only' users completely out of CiviCRM and deliver whatever they might need through Drupal Views, and if necessary, Webforms (for making updates to data)